# onChange trigger is not firing sometimes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

onChange trigger may not fire under the following conditions. Do you know the cause and the remedy?

- Check the checkbox in the spreadsheet
- Select Spreadsheet list

I just created it like this.

1. Create an empty spreadsheet
2. Rewriting the default code

   ```
   function myFunction (event) {
      event.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().setValue(false);
   }
   ```
3. Create onChange trigger
4. Create a checkbox in cell A1
5. Check the check box (about once in 10 times, the process is not executed and it is not displayed in Executions)

Comment: "about once in 10 times, the process is not executed and it is not displayed in Executions" -> How fast are you clicking the checkbox? Have you tried *to count slowly* to 10 before clicking again the checkbox?

Comment: I didn't click that fast. After the execution display is completed, click it.

Comment: It looks that is a platform glitch/ bug... report it through the issue tracker. (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support)

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm reporting it to the issue tracker. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Onchange not firing

Yeah creating an empty spreadsheet is kind of a problem since the new container won't have a trigger inside of it's project.  There are no events that fire upon the editing of script in the script editor.  Yeah creating an onChange trigger that's not covered either I would not hold my breath on that one.  But if you must have it then make it a feature request.  That's enough for me for one question.